# Laravel redis works, but list still empty

Tags: laravel, redis

i'm currently using redis in laravel everything works fine, unless i can't check my redis's keys like normally

I went to "redis-cli " and type "keys *" it shows -empty list or set-

But my cache worked. I tested it with laravel debugbar.

i'm not sure, where and how to check all my redis's keys via command line,

here is my config/database for redis

'redis' => [

```
    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'predis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
        'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', 'helper_'),
    ],
```

thanks

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to modify the file: config/cache.php

Change the `stores` > `redis` > `connection`

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'cache',
    ],
```

to

```
'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
    ],
```

And make sure your `.env` file has `CACHE_DRIVER=redis`

Comment: thanks, can you tel me why we should change this to default instead of cache?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are using default configuration, and have `CACHE_DRIVER` set as `redis`, then you are in fact writing to Redis. However you are by default writing to the database with index `1`

You can see these entries by calling `SELECT 1` followed by `KEYS *` in redis-cli.

You can specify which database to write to in a connection in `config/database.php`. You can then select which connection to use by default in `config/cache.php`.

This is why changing to `default` works in Nazmus Shakib's answer, because the `default` connection outlined in `config/database.php` uses database 0 rather than database 1. Alternatively, you could change `REDIS_CACHE_DB` to 0 in `.env`. Or, you could just use database 1.